# How do I compare equality of two files in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, diff

I have two large `pkl` files. I'm not interested in knowing the comparisons of the contents of two files (as we do for text files with `diff`, `meld` or `vimdiff`). I suspect that they are the same. Their size is equal. But if I want to get certain that they are the same, is there any comparison utility that outputs if they are the same or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) with `-q` option. From [`diff`'s manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html):

> **-q, --brief**
>        report only when files differ

Example usage:

```
$ diff -q a b
Files a and b differ
```

If the files are identical, there will be no output. However, if you want to report if they are identical as well, you can use `-s` option with `-q`.

From the same manpage:

> **-s, --report-identical-files**
>        report when two files are the same

Example usage:

```
$ diff -qs a b
Files a and b are identical
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't suppose this will be any faster than `diff`, but you could compare checksums of the files:

```bsh
md5sum a b | awk '
    NR == 1 {sum_a = $1; next}
    {print ($1 == sum_a) ? "equal" : "different"}
'
```

Comment: Yes, if the files are large, I would suggest you take this advice with `md5sum` instead of any `diff` or `cmp`.  `md5sum` will calculate the checksums one file at a time.  This is probably better than comparing two files in terms of disk activity.  Of course, equality in checksum doesn't guarantee they are the same, but they are probably the same with fairly high probability.

Comment: You may also use `sha1sum`, `sha256sum` or `sha512sum`